# Change colour scales in gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am creating a gif using gganimate of predictions of a keras model by epoch. I have a dataset with the columns `x`, `y`, `prediction`, `epoch`, and I can make my plot using:

```
pred %>%
  filter(epoch == 1) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = prediction)) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd", direction = 1, na.value = NA)
```

I would like to animate over each epoch, by using:

```
pred %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = prediction)) +
  coord_equal() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "YlOrRd", direction = 1, na.value = NA) +
  transition_time(epoch) +
  labs(title= "Epoch: {frame_time}")
```

The issue I have is the predictions are on very different scales over time (start at range 1-10 and finish at around 0.01). Is there any way I can allow the colour scale to change with each frame, so the colour range is similar and the scale changes? I can't get view_follow() to work.